# My div element is ignoring CSS styling with long text

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a list of elements that are set to a certain width. However, for whatever reason, elements with a lot of text are ignoring the CSS to make themselves longer.

```
<ion-view view-title="Events">
<ion-content class="events-body">
    <div ng-repeat="month in vm_events.months | orderBy: 'monthNum'">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="item item-divider">
                {{month.monthName}}
            </div>
            <div class="card eventCard"
                 ng-repeat="event in vm_events.events | filter: {month: month.monthName} | orderBy: 'orderBy'"
                 ui-sref="app.events.event-details({eventID: event.id})">
                <ion-item ui-sref="app.events.event-details({eventID: event.id})">
                    <div class="flex-container eventDay">
                        <div class="flex-item left" ui-sref="app.events.event-details({eventID: event.id})">
                            <div class="flex-item day" ng-show="event.day">{{event.day}}</div>
                            <div class="flex-item tbd" ng-hide="event.day">TBD</div>
                            <div class="flex-item dayOfWeek">{{event.weekday}}</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="flex-item right eventSummary">
                            <div class="name">
                                {{event.name}}
                            </div>
                            <div class="flex-container timeAndPlace">
                                <div class="flex-item place">{{event.location}}</div>
                                <div class="flex-item time">{{event.start}}</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ion-item>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Here's the scss.

```
.events-body {
font-weight: 100;


.card {
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    box-shadow: none;

    .item.item-divider {
        height: 20px;
        min-height: 0;
        border-radius: 0;
        padding: 0 0 0 16px;
        background-color: #909090;

        font-size: 12px;
        color: white;
    }

    .eventCard {
        width: 98%;
        margin: 10px 4px;

        font-size: 16px;
        letter-spacing: 2px;

        ion-item.item.item-complex {
            border-radius: 0;

            a.item-content {
                border-radius: 0;
                padding: 0;

                &.activated .right{
                    background: #8ebce3;

                }
            }

            .left {
                min-width: 21%;
                margin: 0;
                background-color: #e3e3e3;

                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                justify-content: center;

                .flex-item {
                    align-self: center;
                    margin: 0;
                }

                .day {
                    margin: 2px;

                    font-size: 28px;
                }

                .tbd {
                    font-size: 20px;
                }

                .dayOfWeek {
                    font-size: 14px;
                }
            }

            .right {
                width: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 10px 18px;
                background: #4089c9;
                flex-direction: column;

                font-size: 14px;
                color: white;
                line-height: 20px;

                .timeAndPlace {
                    width: 92%;
                    justify-content: space-between;
                    align-items: flex-end;

                    .place {
                        width: 70%;
                        overflow: hidden;
                        text-overflow: ellipsis;
                    }

                    .time {
                        width: 30%;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

.flex-container {
    display: flex;
}
}
```

We use some in-house stuff as well as npm gulp and cordova.  I think I can show this much, though.

No matter how much text I have in the div element, if it's less than a certain length, the width is correct. Otherwise, the width starts adjusting dynamically.  I tried to change it to max-width, but that didn't help anything.

What causes this, and how can I go about fixing it?

**EDIT** - Also, I'm using Chrome's inspect element, and the computed style for this element still says 70% despite not being the same size as the other 70% elements.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your flexbox is meant to grow with it's content.  To prevent this, use max-width on your flexbox items.

```
.flexBox {
  display: flex;
  width: 98%;
  margin: 10px 4px;

  .location {
    width: 70%;
    max-width: 70%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }

  .time {
    max-width: 30%
    width: 30%
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I tried that, but it still didn't change it for some reason.

Comment: Sorry, try using it on the items instead, I updated my answer accordingly

Comment: Thanks again, but it's still not playing nice.
I should probably also add that it says in the element inspector that the width is 70%.

Comment: Ah that changes things.  That means it's your overflow that's not playing nice.

Comment: So I've tried to replicate it using regular div's on codepen as well as ion-items in the ionic playground and so far I've been unsuccessful.  The code above works perfectly for me.  Perhaps @Najam us saqib is correct, but in order to provide further help I would need to see a working example of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put youe CSS file before ionic's default css file.